Study if the function $F(x)=\int_{0}^1D(xu)du$ is differentiable
Given the function $D(x)=\inf\{|x-n|:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, study the differentiability of  $F(x)=\int_{0}^1D(xu)du$.
My try in $0$: $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(h)-F(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^1D(hu)du}{h}=\int_{0}^1\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{D(hu)du}{h}=\int_{0}^1\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h}{h}=1$. So the limit does exist on $0$ and is equal to $1$. To introduce the limit in the integral I argumented with the dominated convergence theorem.
I am stuck with the general case

Is there a $u$ in the definition of $D(u)$ on the RHS? Also do you mean $D(u)$ is the closest integer to $u$? If so, then the given definition does not mean that. Also,  what would be $D(0.5)$? If not, then please clearly define $D(u)$.

@sudeep5221 Was a typo, meant $D(x)$ and no, it does not mean the closest integer, it means the infimum of the distances to all the integers. D(0.5) is 0.5.

For $|x| \le 1/2$ is $D(x) = |x|$, which implies $F(x) = \frac 12 |x|$. So $F$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.
For $ x \ne 0$ is (substitute $v=xu$)
$$
 F(x) = \frac 1x \int_0^x D(v)\, dv 
$$
and that is differentiable at every point $x \ne 0$ because $D$ is continuous. The derivative is
$$
 F'(x) = \frac{D(x)}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2} \int_0^x D(v)\, dv
= \frac{D(x)-F(x)}{x}  \, .
$$
